# Memory Error when applying spacy model to large log file

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am currently working on tokenizing a large log file that contains 39296844 characters. I am using the `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')` model for this text file. Additionally I established the `nlp.max_length = 100000000000` so that I can read very large files. However, when I run the code `doc = nlp(df.iloc[161][1], disable=['ner', 'parser', "textcat"])` where `df.iloc[161][1]` contains the text of the log file, I run into the following memory error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [36], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df["build_log"] = df["build_log"].apply(preprocess)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:4433, in Series.apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4323 def apply(
   4324     self,
   4325     func: AggFuncType,
   (...)
   4328     **kwargs,
   4329 ) -> DataFrame | Series:
   4330     """
   4331     Invoke function on values of Series.
   4332 
   (...)
   4431     dtype: float64
   4432     """
-> 4433     return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1088, in SeriesApply.apply(self)
   1084 if isinstance(self.f, str):
   1085     # if we are a string, try to dispatch
   1086     return self.apply_str()
-> 1088 return self.apply_standard()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1143, in SeriesApply.apply_standard(self)
   1137         values = obj.astype(object)._values
   1138         # error: Argument 2 to "map_infer" has incompatible type
   1139         # "Union[Callable[..., Any], str, List[Union[Callable[..., Any], str]],
   1140         # Dict[Hashable, Union[Union[Callable[..., Any], str],
   1141         # List[Union[Callable[..., Any], str]]]]]"; expected
   1142         # "Callable[[Any], Any]"
-> 1143         mapped = lib.map_infer(
   1144             values,
   1145             f,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
   1146             convert=self.convert_dtype,
   1147         )
   1149 if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], ABCSeries):
   1150     # GH#43986 Need to do list(mapped) in order to get treated as nested
   1151     #  See also GH#25959 regarding EA support
   1152     return obj._constructor_expanddim(list(mapped), index=obj.index)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx:2870, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

Input In [35], in preprocess(text)
      1 def preprocess(text):
----> 2     doc = nlp(text, disable=['ner', 'parser'])
      3     lemmas = [token.lemma_ for token in doc]
      4     commands = get_commands("command-words.txt")

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py:1025, in Language.__call__(self, text, disable, component_cfg)
   1023     raise ValueError(Errors.E109.format(name=name)) from e
   1024 except Exception as e:
-> 1025     error_handler(name, proc, [doc], e)
   1026 if doc is None:
   1027     raise ValueError(Errors.E005.format(name=name))

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py:1630, in raise_error(proc_name, proc, docs, e)
   1629 def raise_error(proc_name, proc, docs, e):
-> 1630     raise e

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py:1020, in Language.__call__(self, text, disable, component_cfg)
   1018     error_handler = proc.get_error_handler()
   1019 try:
-> 1020     doc = proc(doc, **component_cfg.get(name, {}))  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1021 except KeyError as e:
   1022     # This typically happens if a component is not initialized
   1023     raise ValueError(Errors.E109.format(name=name)) from e

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\trainable_pipe.pyx:56, in spacy.pipeline.trainable_pipe.TrainablePipe.__call__()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py:1630, in raise_error(proc_name, proc, docs, e)
   1629 def raise_error(proc_name, proc, docs, e):
-> 1630     raise e

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\trainable_pipe.pyx:52, in spacy.pipeline.trainable_pipe.TrainablePipe.__call__()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\tok2vec.py:125, in Tok2Vec.predict(self, docs)
    123     width = self.model.get_dim("nO")
    124     return [self.model.ops.alloc((0, width)) for doc in docs]
--> 125 tokvecs = self.model.predict(docs)
    126 batch_id = Tok2VecListener.get_batch_id(docs)
    127 for listener in self.listeners:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\model.py:315, in Model.predict(self, X)
    311 def predict(self, X: InT) -> OutT:
    312     """Call the model's `forward` function with `is_train=False`, and return
    313     only the output, instead of the `(output, callback)` tuple.
    314     """
--> 315     return self._func(self, X, is_train=False)[0]

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\chain.py:54, in forward(model, X, is_train)
     52 callbacks = []
     53 for layer in model.layers:
---> 54     Y, inc_layer_grad = layer(X, is_train=is_train)
     55     callbacks.append(inc_layer_grad)
     56     X = Y

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\model.py:291, in Model.__call__(self, X, is_train)
    288 def __call__(self, X: InT, is_train: bool) -> Tuple[OutT, Callable]:
    289     """Call the model's `forward` function, returning the output and a
    290     callback to compute the gradients via backpropagation."""
--> 291     return self._func(self, X, is_train=is_train)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\with_array.py:40, in forward(model, Xseq, is_train)
     38     return model.layers[0](Xseq, is_train)
     39 else:
---> 40     return _list_forward(cast(Model[List2d, List2d], model), Xseq, is_train)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\with_array.py:75, in _list_forward(model, Xs, is_train)
     73 lengths = layer.ops.asarray1i([len(seq) for seq in Xs])
     74 Xf = layer.ops.flatten(Xs, pad=pad)  # type: ignore
---> 75 Yf, get_dXf = layer(Xf, is_train)
     77 def backprop(dYs: List2d) -> List2d:
     78     dYf = layer.ops.flatten(dYs, pad=pad)  # type: ignore

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\model.py:291, in Model.__call__(self, X, is_train)
    288 def __call__(self, X: InT, is_train: bool) -> Tuple[OutT, Callable]:
    289     """Call the model's `forward` function, returning the output and a
    290     callback to compute the gradients via backpropagation."""
--> 291     return self._func(self, X, is_train=is_train)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\chain.py:54, in forward(model, X, is_train)
     52 callbacks = []
     53 for layer in model.layers:
---> 54     Y, inc_layer_grad = layer(X, is_train=is_train)
     55     callbacks.append(inc_layer_grad)
     56     X = Y

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\model.py:291, in Model.__call__(self, X, is_train)
    288 def __call__(self, X: InT, is_train: bool) -> Tuple[OutT, Callable]:
    289     """Call the model's `forward` function, returning the output and a
    290     callback to compute the gradients via backpropagation."""
--> 291     return self._func(self, X, is_train=is_train)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\residual.py:40, in forward(model, X, is_train)
     37     else:
     38         return d_output + dX
---> 40 Y, backprop_layer = model.layers[0](X, is_train)
     41 if isinstance(X, list):
     42     return [X[i] + Y[i] for i in range(len(X))], backprop

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\model.py:291, in Model.__call__(self, X, is_train)
    288 def __call__(self, X: InT, is_train: bool) -> Tuple[OutT, Callable]:
    289     """Call the model's `forward` function, returning the output and a
    290     callback to compute the gradients via backpropagation."""
--> 291     return self._func(self, X, is_train=is_train)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\chain.py:54, in forward(model, X, is_train)
     52 callbacks = []
     53 for layer in model.layers:
---> 54     Y, inc_layer_grad = layer(X, is_train=is_train)
     55     callbacks.append(inc_layer_grad)
     56     X = Y

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\model.py:291, in Model.__call__(self, X, is_train)
    288 def __call__(self, X: InT, is_train: bool) -> Tuple[OutT, Callable]:
    289     """Call the model's `forward` function, returning the output and a
    290     callback to compute the gradients via backpropagation."""
--> 291     return self._func(self, X, is_train=is_train)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\chain.py:54, in forward(model, X, is_train)
     52 callbacks = []
     53 for layer in model.layers:
---> 54     Y, inc_layer_grad = layer(X, is_train=is_train)
     55     callbacks.append(inc_layer_grad)
     56     X = Y

    [... skipping similar frames: Model.__call__ at line 291 (1 times)]

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\chain.py:54, in forward(model, X, is_train)
     52 callbacks = []
     53 for layer in model.layers:
---> 54     Y, inc_layer_grad = layer(X, is_train=is_train)
     55     callbacks.append(inc_layer_grad)
     56     X = Y

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\model.py:291, in Model.__call__(self, X, is_train)
    288 def __call__(self, X: InT, is_train: bool) -> Tuple[OutT, Callable]:
    289     """Call the model's `forward` function, returning the output and a
    290     callback to compute the gradients via backpropagation."""
--> 291     return self._func(self, X, is_train=is_train)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\layers\maxout.py:49, in forward(model, X, is_train)
     47 W = model.get_param("W")
     48 W = model.ops.reshape2f(W, nO * nP, nI)
---> 49 Y = model.ops.gemm(X, W, trans2=True)
     50 Y += model.ops.reshape1f(b, nO * nP)
     51 Z = model.ops.reshape3f(Y, Y.shape[0], nO, nP)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thinc\backends\numpy_ops.pyx:94, in thinc.backends.numpy_ops.NumpyOps.gemm()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\blis\py.pyx:79, in blis.py.gemm()

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 7.87 GiB for an array with shape (7331886, 288) and data type float32
```

I have been trying to figure out the issue for a while and was wondering if anyone knew how to fix this issue? I thought disabling certain components would help but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point of processing ~40m characters as a single string. Do lines separated by `\n` form logical units? In this case read the string line by line and process each line using `pipe()`.

```
text = df.iloc[161][1]
lines = text.split('\n')
processed_lines = nlp.pipe(lines, disable=['ner', 'parser', "textcat"])

# get for example lemmas, nested by line
lemmas_per_line = [[tok.lemma_ for tok in line] for line in processed_lines]
# or if you need them as flat list
lemmas_flat = [lem for line in lemmas_per_line for lem in line]
```

Note that even when using the faster `pipe()` I wouldn't expect SpaCy to process more than ~50k characters per second, so this should take at least 10-12 minutes or possibly much slower depending on your PC and the model used. If you need a progress bar to show progress you can use [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/):

```
from tqdm import tqdm

...
processed_lines = tqdm(nlp.pipe(lines, disable=['ner', 'parser', "textcat"]))
...
```